# Is it safe to use removeAttribute instead of removeAttributeNS?

Tags: javascript, svg, dom, xml-namespaces, dom-manipulation

I'm modifying SVG elements with JavaScript for a program that runs in the Browser. For some element attributes like the `href` of an image element one has to specify the namespace and therefore use the `setAttributeNS` method.

Similar to `setAttribute` and `setAttributeNS` there are methods `removeAttribute` and `removeAttributeNS`. However my testing in Chrome and Firefox shows me that leaving out the namespace and just using `removeAttribute` is fine.

The question is whether this behaviour is by specification or something that Chrome and Firefox added for convenience. And whether I could run into problems in other Browsers or future versions that might drop this behaviour.

### Example

This can be tested in the Browser console:

```
img = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image')
img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/SVG_logo.svg/200px-SVG_logo.svg.png')
```

Outputting the content of variable `img` to the console will result in:

```
img
>   <image href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/SVG_logo.svg/200px-SVG_logo.svg.png"></image>
```

If you want to check whether the namespace has been correctly set you can use:

```
console.dir(img)
```

Or use `img.outerHTML` which will show the namespace prefix:

```
img.outerHTML
>   '<image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/SVG_logo.svg/200px-SVG_logo.svg.png"></image>'
```

Now to the crucial part of removing the attribute:

```
img.removeAttribute('href')
```

Afterwards the output shows that the attribute was removed fine, despite not having used `removeAttributeNS`.

```
img
>   <image></image>
```

### Background

Of course I could just use `removeAttributeNS` if I want to be on the safe side. The reason I'm asking is that I've written something like a wrapper class for the DOM nodes. The wrapper registers all modifications of attributes and can remove them later. If I don't have to use `removeAttributeNS`, the class will be much more lightweight, because then it does not have to save the namespace of each attribute set with `setAttributeNS`.

Comment: In XML this should be different. In HTML not so much as HTML doesn't really know about or support namespaces. Are you testing with an XML document or a HTML document?

Comment: @RobertLongson It's an HTML document with SVG elements included directly in code.